# Recording data using Jack Audio Kit from Python

Tags: python, jack

i am new to jack audio connection kit and don't know work around. i am able to run Jack PortAudio server.
my expectation is to record 60 second audio and save recorded Audio into .wav file.

i am using Python27 and JACK-Client==0.4.6.

Below is the code. please somebody edit this to record and save as .wav file.

```
import jack
import numpy

client = jack.Client('MyGreatClient')

client.inports.register('input_1')
client.outports.register('output_1')

in2 = client.inports.register('input_2')
out2 = client.outports.register('output_2')

client.midi_inports.register('midi_in')
client.midi_outports.register('midi_out')

client.activate()

client.connect('system:capture_1', 'MyGreatClient:input_1')
client.connect('MyGreatClient:output_1', 'system:playback_1')

client.connect(out2, 'system:playback_2')
in2.connect('system:capture_2')
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Not that is relevant to your problem (yet), but why are you using outdated versions of Python and the package?

Then you could look into the [play_file](https://github.com/spatialaudio/jackclient-python/blob/master/examples/play_file.py) example to see how the basic interaction with files and JACK works while using the API. It is not trivial unfortunately.

However, recording and writing is a very valid application as well, but there is no basic example yet. I believe the block buffering and file interaction should happen in a similar fashion as in the play example. Therefore, it would be awesome to figure out how to do that with `soundfile` and create an example in the code base. The maintainer and other users (like myself) should hopefully be able to assist you with that. :)